# why rvalue reference differ between T&& and auto&& for reference proxy in for range loop

Tags: c++

i have encountered the following example in a book i am reading:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T> 
void f1(std::vector<t>& vec)
{
    for (T&& v :vec) { v = true;}
    for (auto&& v : vec) { v = true;}
}

void f2()
{
    using IntVec = std::vector<int>;
    using BoolVec = std::vector<bool>;
    IntVec iv = { /* ...*/};
    BoolVec bv = {/*...*/};
    f1(iv);
    f1(bv);
}
```

loop with T&& fail to compile for IntVec because rvalue reference cannot be initialized from lvalue
reference;
BoolVec does compile but it is written it wont update the container. why ? and why for the auto&& case
both IntVec and BoolVec will compile and update the container ?
i do not understand why for(T&& v:vec) differ from for(auto&& v: vec) ?

Comment: [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is a strange beast and often does not behave like other vectors.

Comment: i used the ctrl-K.

Comment: @anayz Well don't. Anyway I fixed your code formatting.

Comment: I am asking this BECAUSE vector<bool> is a strange beast which return a proxy and not bool directly

Comment: i think the answer is that in case of T&& the for loop converts the temporary proxy to temporary bool so the container is not updated but in the auto case its the temporary proxy itself WHICH BINDS TO V so in the assignment operator=(bool) of the proxy is called and it actually modify the bitfield of the vector

Comment: So you know the answer? The thing with `vector<bool>` is exactly that there are no `bool`s to get references to. So `bool&&` will have a problem with that.

Comment: i didnt know the answer when writing the question. than i thought about it more ...

Comment: Why on earth are people downvoting this?

Comment: @anayz You can answer your own question if you want.  Might be useful for future visitors.  Might even get upvoted :)